# Изменить значения тегов стороннего сайта

Tags: javascript

Есть сторонний сайт с рецептами http://tvoirecepty.ru/recepty
В нем имеется функция выбора рецептов по имеющимся ингредиентам.

Допустим, я хочу хранить имеющийся список у себя в базе данных на компьютере. Как передать значения из базы на данный сайт программно?
Н-р для выбора чеснока необходимо добавить checked элементу

```
 <div class="q" rel="266">(266)</div>
```

Как реализовать это н-р на javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых: checked ловит не этот div, a li на уровень выше. 
Во-вторых: там на элементы навешаны onClick() события.

Но.. Зачем? Пропарсите все, ингредиенты у них хорошо собраны, загоните в базу в адекватном формате, и ищите все с чесноком через sql запрос без какого-либо "checked элементу".